# Nested OL LI lower alpha not working

Tags: css

So we have a reset CSS files that obviously strips everything under the sun out of our styles.

So with any OL LI, i have to explicitly state in our CSS files:

```
#stupidDivTag ol li { list-style-type: decimal; }
```

So when I have this:

```
<ol>
  <li>One
    <ol type="a">
      <li>One Alpha</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

But it does not seem to be working because of the explicit statement.

I do not want to use inline styles, because we have thousands of these.

AND I cannot use another explicit statement such as:

```
#stupidDivTag ol li ol li { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
```

because other nested lists should not use this style.

What am I missing here?

Do I need to create a class for the nested OL LI?

```
<ol class="nestedLowerAlpha">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But it does not seem to be working because of the explicit statement." What isn't working, and what explicit statement are you referring to? The CSS rule? Can you create a demo of the issue?

Comment: You can see the live page here: https://providers.bcidaho.com/medical-management/medical-policies/pd/mp_501150.page Right under the "Policy" header. And yes, I was referring to the CSS rule. It seems to be overriding the inline type rule.

Comment: Shouldn't use by using CSS for that as well? Especially since the type attribute for lists was deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: have you tried adding the specific `class="nestedLowerAlpha"` , it should work

Comment: the class does not work either, just tried it. still remains as decimals

Comment: it's probably overwritten , try adding `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Use the immediate child selector: `>`

```css
#stupidDivTag ol li /* all lis in stupid div tag are decimal */
{
    list-style-type: decimal; 
} 

#stupidDivTag > ol > li > ol > li  /* only second level li will be changed to lower alpha - assuming the first ol is a direct child of stupid div tag */
{ 
    list-style-type: lower-alpha; 
}
```